# Not able to add items to the current list. And not able to redirect after adding the items in current list

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my app.js

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todolistDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const itemsSchema = {
  name: String,
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);

const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Welcome to your todolist!",
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Hit the + button to add a new item.",
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "<-- Hit this to delete an item.",
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

const listSchema ={
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  Item.find()
    .then(function (foundItems) {
      if (foundItems.length === 0)
      {
        Item.insertMany(defaultItems)
          .then(function (defaultItems) {
            console.log("Succesfully added defaultitems to the DB.");
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
          res.redirect("/");
      }
      else
      {
        res.render("list", { listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems });
      }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req,res)
{
  const customListName = req.params.customListName;

  List.findOne({name: customListName}).then(function(foundList) {
    if (!foundList) 
    {
      // creat new List
      const list = new List({
        name: customListName,
        items: defaultItems
      });
      list.save();
      res.redirect("/" + customListName);

    } else 
    {
      // Show existing List
      res.render("list", {listTitle: foundList.name, newListItems: foundList.items});
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) 
{
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  if (listName === "Today") 
  {
    newItem.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  }
  else 
  {
    List.findOne({ name: listName })
      .then((foundList) => {
        foundList.items.push(item);
        foundList.save()
        res.redirect("/" + listName);
      }).catch((err) => 
      {
            console.log(err);
      });
  }
});

app.post("/delete", function(req, res)
{
  const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;

  Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId).then(function(foundItems)
  {

    console.log("Successfully Removed the checkeditem.");
    res.redirect("/");
  }).catch(function(err)
  {
    console.log(err);
  });
})



app.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.render("about");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

this is my list.ejs

```
<%- include("header") -%>

<div class="box" id="heading">
  <h1><%= listTitle %></h1>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>

  <form action="/delete" method="post">
    <div class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item._id %>" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
      <p><%= item.name %></p>
    </div>
  </form>

  <% }); %>

  <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
    <input
      type="text"
      name="newItem"
      placeholder="New Item"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
    <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
  </form>
</div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

i want to add items in current list. and after creating multiple list i want to add items in individual list and save it to the database. Some times it showing this

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'items') how to solve this error

Please Help Me with this

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error seems to be due to foundList object is null, meaning that no list with the specified name was found in your database. To solve this error, you should first check if there is foundList in db before accessing its properties.
To achive this you can modify your app.post("/") route as follows:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) 
{
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  });

  if (listName === "Today") 
  {
    newItem.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  }
  else 
  {
    List.findOne({ name: listName })
      .then((foundList) => {
        if (foundList) {
          foundList.items.push(item);
          foundList.save()
          res.redirect("/" + listName);
        } else {
          console.log("List not found");
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      }).catch((err) => 
      {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/");
      });
  }
});
```

Similarly, you can modify your app.get("/:customListName") route to handle the case where no list is found in your database as well.